# RabbitMQ prefetch ignored when consumer is Down and gets Up

Tags: rabbitmq, prefetch, consumer

I'm getting my basicQos ignored when consumer is down and, after, consumer gets up. For instance, suppose that consumer is down and 5 messages arrives from a producer. If consumer is not running, these messages will be stored in disk (I think!) if exchanger/queue is (are) durable.

if I set basicQos as channel.basicQos(0, 3, true), my consumer receives more than 3 messages when it gets UP. Why?!?

On the other hand, everything works properly (only 3 messages are read from the queue) if consumer is running when it receives messages from the queues... My code is as follows:

```
factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost(mRabbitMQHost); //may get server address from file configuration.
factory.setUsername(mRabbitMQUsername); 
factory.setPassword(mRabbitMQPassword);
connection = factory.newConnection();
channel = connection.createChannel();

channel.exchangeDeclare("exchangeName", "direct", true); //True enables durability
consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);

for (QGQueues queue : QGQueues.values()) {
    String queueName = queue.getQueueName();
    channel.queueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
    channel.queueBind(queueName, "exchangeName", queue.getRoutingKey());
    channel.basicConsume(queueName, false, consumer); //false enables ACK message to RabbitMQ server    
}

channel.basicQos(0, 3, true);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I solved the problem. basicQos must be called before defining consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet would be that you need to set the QoS before you do anything else.

Change your code to this order:

```
channel = connection.createChannel();

// set QoS immediately
channel.basicQos(0, 3, true);

channel.exchangeDeclare("exchangeName", "direct", true); //True enables durability
consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);

for (QGQueues queue : QGQueues.values()) {
    String queueName = queue.getQueueName();
    channel.queueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
    channel.queueBind(queueName, "exchangeName", queue.getRoutingKey());
    channel.basicConsume(queueName, false, consumer); //false enables ACK message to RabbitMQ server    
}
```

this will ensure the prefetch limit is set before you try to consume any messages.

Comment: Thanks, Derick! That's exactly the solution!

Comment: Yes, basicQos is telling RabbitMQ how the consumer expects to receive messages, so it has to be sent before basicConsume